# Is it possible for a single Django template to render to multiple objects?

Tags: django, django-templates

Is there any way use Django's templating system to render a template file and to return three discrete objects?

Use case: I'm putting together an email that is to be rendered based on some request parameters.  Each email consists of a) a subject, b) a plain-text version, c) a html version. Ideally, I'd like to have all of these to be sourced from a single template file rather than three separate files, to make for easier maintenance.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can include conditional loops in your template using Django's template engine? Although in your case, the template inheriting system might be the right tool after all because it nicely separates different use cases.

Comment: You can checkout the `include` tag; or try creating custom tag; I worked in django a long ago; can't remember now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use render_to_string, passing in an argument of which section to render. That would allow you to use one template and render a portion of the template at a time.

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

subject = render_to_string('the-template.html',
    {'section': 'subject', 'subject': 'Foo bar baz'})
plain_text = render_to_string('the-template.html',
    {'section': 'text', 'text': 'Some text'})
html = render_to_string('the-template.html',
    {'section': 'html', 'html': '<p>Some html</p>'})


#the-template.html
{% if section == 'subject' %}
    {{ subject }}
{% elif section == 'text' %}
    {{ plain_text }}
{% else %}
    <h1>A headline, etc.</h1>
    {{ html }}
{% endif %}
```

You can also pass whatever values you need from the incoming request to the template in the context.

Comment: Looks great! In the process of researching this, I ran across this Django module which I will probably use: https://github.com/bradwhittington/django-templated-email; but your solution would work as well. Thanks!